# Gnus: mark all articles older than X-month as read

Tags: gnus

When I visit usenet or gmane group for the first time I want to see only recent articles.

Is it possible to mark articles as read based on their publication date?

Answer (score 3):

You can use / t to limit the article in a *Summary* to a number of days:

> / t runs the command gnus-summary-limit-to-age, which is an
>   interactive compiled Lisp function in `gnus-sum.el'.
>
> It is bound to / t,    .
>
> (gnus-summary-limit-to-age AGE &optional YOUNGER-P)
>
> Limit the summary buffer to articles that are older than (or equal)
>   AGE days. If YOUNGER-P (the prefix) is non-nil, limit the summary
>   buffer to articles that are younger than AGE days.

You are prompted: "Limit to articles older than (in days, younger when negative): " when using / t

So you should be able to limit the articles shown to the ones older than 30*n days, and then mark those as read?

Comment: Nice tip! One issue with your solution - when I visit new newsgroup there are a lot of messages (5000-200000) I like to strip history older then in 2010 or other year and sniff around the rest. Rarely I am in that situation. I don't like a solution which mean simply to download all article just to strip most of them especially when I on high cost mobile network connection.

Comment: I guess the easiest is to catch up the group, so everything is read, and then use / t to find the messages you are interested in, and mark those as unread. I don't think you'll be able to select/deselection articles by date without downloading the headers.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the temporary solution:

- mark group as read with <kbd>c</kbd> (which is bound to
  `gnus-topic-catchup-articles`) in `*Group*` buffer while point is placed
  on group of interest
- enter the group (press <kbd>RET</kbd> or specify how many latest articles
  should be displayed using numeric argument, e.g. <kbd>C-u 1 2 3 RET</kbd>)
- load as many articles as you want using something like <kbd>/ o 123
  RET</kbd> (this runs `gnus-summary-insert-old-articles`) and repeat it
  until you're satisfied with publication date of oldest loaded article
- mark every article as unread with <kbd>M-u</kbd>
  (`gnus-summary-clear-mark-forward`) or mark all articles with <kbd>M P
  a</kbd> (`gnus-uu-mark-all`) and apply command to each article <kbd>M-&
  M-u</kbd> (`gnus-summary-universal-argument`).

I am not satisfied with this solution. Better solution would be to simply
specify how many months of history I want to fetch.